# Which device to attach filter driver to for Xbox 360 controller?

Tags: filter, driver, wdk, joystick

As a learning exercise, I'm trying to write a filter driver for the wired XBox 360 controller on Windows 7 64-bit. This controller shows up as a HID joystick, so it seems like it should be straightforward.

I've made an example filter driver for my mouse which swaps the left and right mouse buttons. This was based on the moufiltr and firefly samples that come with the WDK. However, I'm having trouble converting this example to work for the XBox 360 controller.

When I plug the controller in, 3 different devices appear in device manager:

- Human Interface Devices/HID-compliant game controller
- Human Interface Devices/USB Human Interface Device
- Common Controller for Windows Class/Xbox 360 Controller for Windows

Which one of these should I attach my driver to?

With the mouse filter driver, I was able to follow the [installation directions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff541876%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) from the firefly sample: right-click on the mouse in device manager, choose "update driver." With the XBox 360 controller, I'm not sure which device I should install my driver for. Or are they all talking to the hardware independently, and I would need to install a filter for each one of them?

I should note that I've tried attaching a filter driver to each of the 3 devices in order to print out the IOCTLs available to my filter driver. For the "USB Human Interface Device" my filter received no IOCTLs.

For the HID-compliant game controller, it received:

- IOCTL_HID_GET_COLLECTION_INFORMATION (multiple times)
- IOCTL_HID_GET_COLLECTION_DESCRIPTOR (multiple times)
- IOCTL_GET_SYS_BUTTON_CAPS

For the Xbox 360 Controller for Windows, it receive a bunch of IOCTLs that I can't track down a symbolic name for:

- 0x80006000 (multiple times)
- 0x8000e00c (multiple times)
- 0x8000e008
- 0x8000a010
- 0x8000e018
- 0x8000e014

Unfortunately I still don't know which device I should be attempting to filter. (I was hoping one of them would be receiving joystick-equivalent of IOCTL_INTERNAL_MOUSE_CONNECT, but that does not appear to be the case.)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to filter the internal IOCTLs (specifically IOCTL_HID_GET_INPUT_REPORT/IOCTL_HID_READ_REPORT)

You have probably been filtering EvtIoDeviceControl try EvtIoInternalDeviceControl and look for the read/get-input report ioctl, this will originate from whatever system service wants to read the joystick events.

Once you manage to filter the right ioctl you will need to look at the report descriptor for that joystick to figure out how to interpret (and then modify) the data.

Answer (score 0):

From xusb22.sys XInputRequestDispatcher::Dispatch():

```cpp
0x80006000 DispatchGetInformation((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer, (ULONG)ioctlCode);
0x8000A010 DispatchSetState((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
0x8000A01C DispatchPowerDownDevice((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
0x8000E004 DispatchGetCapabilities((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
0x8000E008 DispatchGetLedState((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer)
0x8000E00C DispatchGetState((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
0x8000E014 DispatchWaitForGuideButton((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer)
0x8000E018 DispatchGetBatteryInformation((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
0x8000E020 DispatchGetAudioDeviceInformation((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
0x8000E3AC DispatchWaitForInput((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (struct XenonBusInformation *)&v6, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
0x8000E3FC DispatchGetInformationEx((XInputRequestServicers *)this, (WDFREQUEST)request, (RequestBuffers*)buffer);
```

So accordind to this, we can reverse engineer codes:

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

// https://learn.microsoft.com/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/defining-i-o-control-codes
// {EC87F1E3-C13B-4100-B5F7-8B84D54260CB}
DEFINE_GUID(XUSB_INTERFACE_CLASS_GUID, 0xEC87F1E3, 0xC13B, 0x4100, 0xB5, 0xF7, 0x8B, 0x84, 0xD5, 0x42, 0x60, 0xCB);

// xusb22.sys IOCTLs
#define FILE_DEVICE_XUSB    0x8000
#define IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB    0x0800

#define IOCTL_XUSB_GET_INFORMATION              /*0x80006000*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 0, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_GET_CAPABILITIES             /*0x8000E004*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 1, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_GET_LED_STATE                /*0x8000E008*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 2, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_GET_STATE                    /*0x8000E00C*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 3, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_SET_STATE                    /*0x8000A010*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 4, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_WAIT_GUIDE_BUTTON            /*0x8000E014*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 5, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_GET_BATTERY_INFORMATION      /*0x8000E018*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 6, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_POWER_DOWN                   /*0x8000A01C*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 7, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_GET_AUDIO_DEVICE_INFORMATION /*0x8000E020*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 8, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_WAIT_FOR_INPUT               /*0x8000E3AC*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 235, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
#define IOCTL_XUSB_GET_INFORMATION_EX           /*0x8000E3FC*/ CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_XUSB, IOCTL_INDEX_XUSB + 255, METHOD_BUFFERED, FILE_READ_ACCESS | FILE_WRITE_ACCESS)
```